# Ativar recurso de 'zoom' dos navegadores mobile em dropdown

Tags: css, html5

Existe a possibilidade de simular o 'zoom' que os navegadores mobile implementam no `select`, em um `dropdown`?

Ex: Quando o usuário clica em um `select`, o próprio navegador cria uma modal, fazendo com que o usuário consiga selecionar a opção desejada de um jeito bem mais fácil.

Comment: Você quer impedir a ação *default* do navegador e criar a sua própria forma de exibir os itens do `select`?

Comment: @renan, não... na verdade quero fazer exatamente o contrário: quero simular a ação _default_ do navegador para o **select** em um **dropdown**

Comment: Não...pode ser com jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma forma é criar um elemento falso, com aparência de um *dropdpwn / select* mas que na verdade não faz nada, isto é, sendo algo somente visual. Por exemplo:

```css
.fake-dropdown {
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #888;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 8px;
    max-width: 220px;
}

.fake-dropdown > i {
    float: right
}
```

```html
<!--
   incluindo o 'font awesome' somente para mostrar uma seta para baixo no
   'select / dropdown'
-->
<link rel='stylesheet' href='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'/>


<div class='fake-dropdown'>
    Selecione uma opção <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
</div>
```

Quando este falso *select* houver evento de click, deve então exibir um outro elemento responsável por cobrir toda a página. Nesse outro elemento serão exibidas as opções que o *select* poderia ter. Por exemplo:

```css
ul{list-style:none}
a{text-decoration: none}

.dropdown-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0;
    right: 0; left: 0;
    background: #333;
    
    display: -webkit-flex;
     display: -ms-flexbox;
            display: flex;

    -webkit-align-items: center;
      -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
         align-items: center;
  
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.dropdown-content li a {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

.dropdown-content li:first-child a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #31b0d5
}
```

```html
<div class='dropdown-content'>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a id='fechar' href='#'>Fechar dropdown</a>
            <li><a href='#'>Início</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Calcular rota</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Mostrar rota mais rápido</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Mostrar rota mais econômica</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Então você pode criar uma classe responsável por mostrar o conteúdo desse *dropdown* (que primeiramente se mostrará escondido), tal classe pode conter as seguintes regras:

```
.dropdown-content {
   /*... as demais regras, mostradas acima */

   /* as duas abaixo é para exibir o elemento escondido e,
      atrás do conteúdo da página*/
   visibility: hidden;
   z-index: -999;
}

.visible {
    visibility: visible;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Para exibir o conteúdo de `dropdown-content`, basta incluir a classe `.visible` no mesmo elemento com Javascript. Como você disse que não tem problemas utilizar jQuery, segue um exemplo (com as regras acima) funcionando:

```js
$(function(){
    $("#abrir,#fechar").on('click', function(){
      $('.dropdown-content').toggleClass('visible');
    });
});
```

```css
*{margin: 0;padding:0}
ul{list-style:none}
a{text-decoration: none}

.fake-dropdown {
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #888;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 8px;
    max-width: 220px;
}

.fake-dropdown > i {
    float: right
}

.dropdown-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0;
    right: 0; left: 0;
    background: #333;
    
    display: -webkit-flex;
     display: -ms-flexbox;
            display: flex;

    -webkit-align-items: center;
      -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
         align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: -999;
}

.dropdown-content li a {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

.dropdown-content li:first-child a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #31b0d5
}

.visible {
    visibility: visible;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'/>


<div id='abrir' class='fake-dropdown'>
    Selecione uma opção <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
</div>

<div class='dropdown-content'>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a id='fechar' href='#'>Fechar dropdown</a>
            <li><a href='#'>Início</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Calcular rota</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Mostrar rota mais rápido</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Mostrar rota mais econômica</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```